# Symfony2 and Joins

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm totally off the balance now, since I spend couple of hours googling and found nothing solid. I want to do a `leftJoin` in Symfony2 (using Doctrine). From the docs, I'm here:

```
$ownRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('GameShelfUsersBundle:Ownership');

$ownQuery = $ownRepo->createQueryBuilder('own')
    ->where('own.user = :user')
    ->andWhere('own.own = :type')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'user' => $user,
        'type' => $type
    ))
    ->orderBy('own.updated','desc')
    ->getQuery();

$own = $ownQuery->getResult();
```

Now, for God's sake, how do I do `leftJoin`? I tried adding

> ->leftJoin('GameShelfGamesBundle:Games','g')

with various additions (`ON own.game = g.id` etc) but it doesn't work at all. Any help? I'm still a novice in this ;(

Comment: please paste your entity code; The join is based on the relationships you setup between your entities

Answer (score 3):

Symfony2 is using Doctrine2 as a ORM, so looking this topic up in the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/) is a good idea. From the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods):

```
leftJoin('own.games', 'g')
```

This only works if the property in your Ownership class is called `games`!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure if I follow, even though I read the docs before posting. Can you post some example of setting those relations? Earlier, I worked with CodeIgniter and SQL alone, and Doctrine - as fascinating as it is - is hard to understand.